# openMP invalid controlling predicate

Tags: c++, c, openmp

here in this code, I'm trying to do Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm in parallel using OpenMP when the program is serial it's working fine in

> for (int i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
> prime[i] = false;

but when I'm using

> #pragma omp for

it give this error

> error: invalid controlling predicate
> 17 |     for (int p = 2; p * p <= n; p++)

this is the code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;
 
void SieveOfEratosthenes(int n)
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    bool prime[n + 1];
    memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));
    #pragma omp for 
    for (int p = 2; p * p <= n; p++)
    {
        
        if (prime[p] == true)
        {
            for (int i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
                prime[i] = false;
        }
    }
    
    #pragma omp critical
    for (int p = 2; p <= n; p++)
        if (prime[p])
            printf("%d  ", p);
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    printf("Enter the siza: ");
    int n ;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Following are the prime numbers from 1 to %f \n", sqrt(n));
    SieveOfEratosthenes(sqrt(n));
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check OpenMP specs, your form of loop test expression is not supported: https://www.openmp.org/specifications/. It needs to be either _var relational-op ub_ or _ub relational-op var_, where you have _var binary-op var relational-op ub_.

Comment: The Sieve of Eratosthenes is difficult to parallelize effectively because it has a lot of data dependencies.  I once managed to do it (albeit not with OpenMP), and the resulting speedup was disappointing because of all the overhead required to satisfy those dependencies.

Comment: My guess is that it is a university homework, moreover `n` should be small as array `prime` created on the stack, so performance is not an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Daniel Langr your form of loop test is not supported. It has to be a canonical loop form. For more details see [2.9.1 Canonical Loop Form](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu40.html#x63-1260002.9.1) of the OpenMP specification. Taking the square root of both sides of comparison you can change it to a supported form:

```
const int end_p=sqrt(n);
#pragma omp for 
for (int p = 2; p <= end_p; p++)
```

Note that your code has other error as well: each thread will create a private `prime` array and work on their private copy, so you obtain incorrect result. You can correct it by using shared `prime` array and atomic read and write operations:

```
void SieveOfEratosthenes(int n)
{    
    bool prime[n + 1];
    memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));
    
    const int end_p=sqrt(n);
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int p = 2; p <= end_p; p++)
    {
        bool prime_p;
        #pragma omp atomic read
        prime_p=prime[p];
        if (prime_p == true)
        {
            for (int i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
            {
                #pragma omp atomic write
                prime[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int p = 2; p <= n; p++)
        if (prime[p])
            printf("%d  ", p);
    
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, atomic reads and writes are not sufficient because the SoE depends on the primes being discovered in ascending order.  Atomic operations solve the data race problem, but not the data dependencies.

Comment: @John Bollinger Yes, you are right. This code is not exactly SoE and less efficient, but I think it gives correct result. Am I right? At least [CodeExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nKPz8oK8Y) gives the same result if OpenMP used or not.

Comment: Yes, on second glance, you are right.  The code does not implement standard SoE.  What it does implement trades efficiency for relief from the data dependency issue.  Under what conditions this is a favorable exchange is a potentially interesting question, though one that I suspect has already been answered.

Comment: @Laci Hello, Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71790722/showing-the-variation-in-elapsed-time-with-number-of-threads-change-in-openmp-co     This is based on your solution.