# showing the variation in elapsed time with number of threads change in openMP code

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, openmp

I have implemented Sieve of Eratosthenes to find out the prime numbers using openMp method for various term values and thread.

Here is my code

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<omp.h>
 

void SieveOfEratosthenes(int n)
{  
      
    bool prime[n + 1];
    memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));
    
    const int end_p=sqrt(n);
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int p = 2; p <= end_p; p++)
    {
        bool prime_p;
        #pragma omp atomic read
        prime_p=prime[p];
        if (prime_p == true)
        {
            for (int i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
            {
                #pragma omp atomic write
                prime[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int p = 2; p <= n; p++)
        if (prime[p])
            printf("%d  ", p);
    
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        int procs;
        int term =100;
        double start,finish;
        procs = omp_get_num_procs();
        omp_set_num_threads(procs);
        start = omp_get_wtime();
        SieveOfEratosthenes(term);
        finish = omp_get_wtime();
        printf("Elapsed time = %e seconds\n", finish - start);

        return 0;
}
```

I am going to show the output of elapsed time for various terms and threads

Here is the result:

```
1.term=100
a)Thread 1 , elapsed time= 3.879014e-04 seconds
b)Thread 2, elapsed time = 3.887471e-04 seconds
c)Thread 4, elapsed time = 3.742063e-04 seconds
d)Thread 8, elapsed time = 3.988100e-04 seconds
e)Thread 16, elapsed time = 5.262811e-04 seconds

2.term = 100000
a)Thread 1, elapsed time = 6.131708e-03
b)Thread 2, elapsed time = 4.231855e-03
c)Thread 4, elapsed time = 4.193152e-03
d)Thread 8, elapsed time = 6.109135e-03
e)Thread 16, elapsed time = 4.225969e-03

3.term = 100000000
a)Thread 1, elapsed time = 1.237387e+01
b)Thread 2, elapsed time = 1.184531e+01
c)Thread 4, elapsed time = 1.160130e+01
d)Thread 8, elapsed time = 1.128761e+01
e)Thread 16, elapsed time = 1.18116e+01seconds
```

Now I can see from the statistics when term is 100 elapsed time increased for thread 8,16(1-d),e))

When term = 100000, elapsed time is increased for thread 8(2 d)), then again decrease.

When term = 100000000, elapsed time is increased in for number of threads 16 than number of threads 8.

My confusion is when the task divided on number of threads elapsed time should decrease. I mean if the number of threads increased elapsed time decreased. However, I saw a variation in my result.

It would be great if someone help me to find out what I missed in my code.

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you remove the atomic operations (see my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69450314/openmp-invalid-controlling-predicate/69452857#69452857))? How do you set the number of threads?

Comment: I saw that atomic operation did not have any effect on the code. I got same result with them without them. for compilation`$ gcc -O2 -fopenmp -o prime prime.c`, for interactive session ` srun -p node -n 10 -N 1 --pty --mem 10000 -t 10:00 bash`, for execution  `./prime 4` where 4 is number of thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `omp_set_num_threads(thread_count);` in your `main` to set the number of threads.
2. Exclude the printout from speed measurement, as it has nothing to do with the calculation and it is the slowest part of your code.
3. Use dynamic schedule `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)`. The load balance is not optimal using the default schedule, because the bigger the `p` the lower the workload.
4. Your code has a race condition, which is undefined behavior in C language.

> I saw that atomic operation did not have any effect on the code. I got
> same result with them without them.

Please understand that even if you happen to get correct results on a given compiler/architecture (e.g. x86/64), it does not necessarily mean that your code is correct. Your code should work properly (and as designed) using any compilers/computer architectures.

5. After these changes, I see speedup:

```
term=100000000;
Thread 1, Elapsed time = 6.903768e-01 seconds
Thread 8, Elapsed time = 2.813646e-01 seconds
```

Comment: I got the error undefined reference to `omp_set_num_thread" .  I have chenged my code in the question section.

Comment: `omp_set_num_threads` (s was missing): https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu110.html

Comment: `int thread_count = omp_get_num_threads();` It is always 1, because it is called from the sequential part of a program. https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu111.html

Comment: I have changed the code as you have suggested but got an error `undefined reference to `omp_get_num_procs`. Can you please make changes in my code block so that I can run it without error.

Comment: Your code compiles without an error in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zfejhn3n1). Note that by default all the available threads are used, so you can skip these lines `procs = omp_get_num_procs();  omp_set_num_threads(procs);`.