# Find prime numbers from a given range of numbers parallel program

Tags: c, multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I tried to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes method to find prime numbers.

This is my code block

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<omp.h>


char isPrime[1000];     

// odd-only sieve
int eratosthenesOdd(int N, int useOpenMP)
{
        /* enable/disable OpenMP */
        omp_set_num_threads(useOpenMP ? omp_get_num_procs() : 1);

        /* instead of i*i <= N we write i <= sqr(N) to help OpenMP */
        const int NSqrt = (int)sqrt((double)N);
        int memorySize = (N-1)/2;


        int i, j;
        /* Let all numbers be prime initially */
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (i = 0; i <= memorySize; i++){
                isPrime[i] = 1;
        }


        /* find all odd non-primes */
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
        for (i = 3; i <= NSqrt; i += 2){
                if (isPrime[i/2]){
                        for (j = i*i; j <= N; j += 2*i){
                                isPrime[j/2] = 0;
                        }
                }
        }

        printf("2\n")   
        for(int k=3;k<=N;k+=2){
                if(isPrime[k/2]==1){
                        printf("%d ", k);
                }
        }

        /* sieve is complete, count primes */
        int total = N >= 2 ? 1 : 0;
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:total)
        for (i = 1; i <= memorySize; i++){
                total += isPrime[i];
        }

        return total;
}

int main()
{
        double start, finish;
        start =  omp_get_wtime();
        int total = eratosthenesOdd(100, 1);
        finish = omp_get_wtime();
        printf("\n %d", total);
        printf("\n Elapsed time=%e seconds", finish-start);
        return 0;
}
```

I got reference from [here](https://create.stephan-brumme.com/eratosthenes/#basic). The code is running well and I can find how many prime numbers are in the given range.

I am skeptical about the elapsed time that I got after several trial with same number of term.

Lets suppose I want to see the prime numbers between 1 to 100. I also want to find out the elapsed time for various threads.

```
1st trial
N=100
Number of Thread  1, elapsed time = 5.008094e-04
Number of Thread  8, elapsed time = 4.649349e-04
Number of Thread 16, elapsed time = 4.652534e-04

2nd trial
N=100
Number of Thread  1, elapsed time = 4.668552e-04sec
Number of Thread  8, elapsed time = 5.837623e-04sec
Number of Thread 16, elapsed time = 5.835127e-04sec

 3rd trial
 N=100
Number of Thread  1, elapsed time = 4.530195e-04 sec
Number of Thread  8, elapsed time = 4.66317e-04sec
Number of Thread 16, elapsed time = 6.141420e-04 sec
```

I wonder is this program really implement parallel program? If so, how could I get this variation in times? Also, when task divide among threads the time should have decrease with compare to serial time. But here this was not happened.

Comment: You can scan through the `isPrime` array after the sieve is finished; if `isPrime[i]` is `1`, then `i` is a prime number.  Iterate over any range within the bounds of the array to list the prime numbers.

Comment: Note that you have data race when accessing `isPrime` and `j`. I suggest you to read a decent book about OpenMP and always define your variables in their minimum required scope. I also suggest you to use `default(none)` clause, so you have to explicitly define the sharing attributes of your variables.

Comment: `const int NSqrt = (int)sqrt((double)N);` is prone to problems when `sqrt(N)` returns xxx.999999999999 and not the expected xxx.0.  `const int NSqrt = lround(sqrt((double)N));` is better.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have changed the code block as per your suggestion. I believe I did not follow your comment correctly so that I got the result which is the mixer of prime and non prime number. Can you please explain me how can I get correct output.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica There are other problem as well in the code block can you please edit it? Thank you.

Comment: @Encipher Best for the author of the question to edit the question.

Comment: When the sieve operation is complete, each element of the `isPrime` array should either contain 0, indicating that the index is a composite number, or 1, indicating that the index is a prime number.  Therefore, a loop along the lines of `for (int i = 2; i < 1000; i++) { if (isPrime[i]) printf("%d\n", i); }` should print the prime numbers, one per line.  If composite numbers appear in the output, there is a bug in your sieve algorithm, maybe caused by data races.  If run single-threaded, you should get the correct output. If you run it multi-threaded and get a different answer, there's a bug.

Comment: I missed that the code optimizes the storage by indexing by `i/2`.  It knows that 2 is prime and that every other even number is composite.  The data type is `char` to reduce the memory usage (probably by a factor of 4) compared to using `int`.  You can go further and use an array of bits — that allows you to deal with 8 times as many values in the same storage space as the `char` array.

Comment: As I mentioned you have data races. To correct it you just have to do exactly the same thing that was discussed in your past 2-3 questions about finding prime numbers. E.g. [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71790722/showing-the-variation-in-elapsed-time-with-number-of-threads-change-in-openmp-co) (3rd revision) is fine from OpenMP point of view. Please notice the difference: it contains atomic reads/writes and you have used `for (int i = ...)` instead of `for (j = ...)` (you declared a variable inside a parallel region, which makes it a private variable)

Comment: @Laci Previous version of my openmp code had the same problem as this version. The elapsed time should decrease with number of thread increase but it did not. Therefore, I switched to the new version written here.

Comment: While your code gives incorrect results and it has undefined behavior you should not worry about its speed.  Note that if `N=1000000` you will see speedup, if `N=100` you do not need any speedup at all. In the latter case the parallel overhead is much bigger than the gain by parallelization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the OMP software installed, so I had to remove the parallelization.  However, the code works once the 'print out the prime numbers' loop is adjusted to deal with the fact that the algorithm knows that 2 is the only even prime number and that it stores the primality of an odd number X in `isPrime[X / 2]`.

This leads to this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
//#include <omp.h>

static char isPrime[1000];

// odd-only sieve
//static int eratosthenesOdd(int N, int useOpenMP)
static int eratosthenesOdd(int N)
{
    /* enable/disable OpenMP */
    //omp_set_num_threads(useOpenMP ? omp_get_num_procs() : 1);

    /* instead of i*i <= N we write i <= sqr(N) to help OpenMP */
    const int NSqrt = (int)sqrt((double)N);
    int memorySize = (N - 1) / 2;

    int i, j;
    /* Let all numbers be prime initially */
    //#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i = 0; i <= memorySize; i++)
    {
        isPrime[i] = 1;
    }


    /* find all odd non-primes */
    //#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
    for (i = 3; i <= NSqrt; i += 2)
    {
        if (isPrime[i / 2])
        {
            for (j = i * i; j <= N; j += 2 * i)
            {
                isPrime[j / 2] = 0;
            }
        }
    }


    printf("2\n");
    for (int k = 3; k <= N; k += 2)
    {
        if (isPrime[k / 2] == 1)
        {
            printf("%d\n", k);
        }
    }

    /* sieve is complete, count primes */
    int total = N >= 2 ? 1 : 0;
    //#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:total)
    for (i = 1; i <= memorySize; i++)
    {
        total += isPrime[i];
    }

    return total;
}

int main(void)
{
    //int total = eratosthenesOdd(100, 1);
    int total = eratosthenesOdd(100);
    printf("Number of primes: %d\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

And this output:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97
Number of primes: 25
```

By inspection, this is correct for the primes up to 100.

Comment: Thank you. The code is running in parallel platform as well. But the performance metric made me skeptical about the way parallel implementation done here.

Comment: Adding parallelism does not necessarily speed things up.  It depends on the costs of synchronization vs the benefit of parallel operation.

Comment: But isn't it weird that same number of term with same number of threads show different results in different trails.

Comment: It depends on how the OMP code synchronizes things and parallelizes things.  The Sieve of Eratosthenes (at least in naïve implementations) assumes that while it is processing a prime P, all smaller primes have already been identified and their (odd) multiples have been marked as non-prime (composite).  It isn't entirely clear, therefore, that parallelism can buy you any speed up.  And if that assumption is violated, then you can easily end up with incorrect results.  Does the OMP synchronization ensure that assumption?

Comment: @Encipher - you may like this live-GUI tool https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zfrrlfeiji to see how much we can pay, not to lose more than gaining from parallel code-execution. In other words, for tiny problems ( not much to process ) the add-on overhead costs of going into concurrent code-execution may ( and often do ) grow way larger, than the expected ( theoretical + principally constrained ) speedup. If one pays way more than receiving ever back, such investment was a pure loss. Also never test on scales under 1E9, if trying to indeed go into hard facts, not skewed by noise & coincidence.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Could you enlighten us on what benefit comes from an attempt to "parallelise" a pre-fill a block of RAM with a byte-wise mapping of 1-s, if being done by `#pragma omp parallel for` given a number of omp_set_num_threads() launched threads could be awfully highm yet having but a very few actual CPU-RAM memory-I/O channels (and awfully high cache-re-synchronisation costs of per-thread thousand time invalidated cache re-broadcasting of newly written content to all other cores' on-core local replicas? A compiler-phase block-wide pre-fill would be a fair step here,given hidden costs

Comment: ^ your code analysed here https://godbolt.org/z/nPPcGEjef --- see assembly blocks ( actual costs of individual sections of proposed source-code - both productive and add-on overhead costs' instructions interactively visible + dependency-graph of the code that implemented the said algorithm )

Comment: @user3666197: I cannot enlighten you — can you enlighten me?  I don't think the project is very suitable for parallelization. The processing for any given number  depends on the previous numbers having been done correctly, which is the very antithesis of parallelizable.  And for problem sizes under a million (he says, pulling a largish number out of thin air), I'm tolerably certain that the setup, teardown and running overheads far outweigh the benefit of whatever parallelization is possible.

Comment: At least, deducing which is the next prime to work with — that one step requires the previous numbers to have completed that bit.  The chasing through the list setting multiples of the prime to 0 can be parallelized, though there is arguably still a need to synchronize the writes, which is expensive.