# Can't find the race condition

Tags: c++, openmp, race-condition

I'm writing a program to count prime numbers from 2 to N using OpenMP. I wrote this code and while testing it, for example, with N = 10 (OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./main 10) I get mostly 4-s but sometimes I get 5-s in my output. It seems like there is a race condition that I cannot see and I don't now where it is. Can you help me to find this condition and get rid of it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
        return -1;

    const unsigned long N = std::atoi(argv[1]);

    unsigned counter = 0;
    std::vector<bool> numbers(N + 1, true);
    numbers[0] = numbers[1] = false;

#pragma omp parallel shared(numbers, counter)
    {
#pragma omp single
        {
            for (size_t i = 2; i * i <= N; ++i)
            {
                if (numbers[i] == true)
#pragma omp task
                {
                    for (size_t j = i * i; j <= N; j += i)
                        numbers[j] = false;
                }
            }
#pragma omp taskwait
        }
#pragma omp for reduction(+ \
                          : counter)
        for (size_t i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
            if (numbers[i] == true)
                counter++;
    }

    std::cout << counter << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: appreciate all the help in the comments. Calling sanitizer really helped to detect a data race condition. Adding "#pragma for critical"  for the `numbers[j]=false` does solve the problem with multiple writings and dealing with race conditions.
But this works only for big numbers N, when we have multiple `false` writes in same position.
So I want to return previous question to particular case with N=10:
here are no multiple writings in same region, take a look at cycles:
`(size_t i = 2; i * i <= N; ++i)` will give us i = 2,3. So with `for (size_t j = i * i; j <= N; j += i)` we will have j = 4,6,8,10,9.
After this I took a look at the output "numbers" vector, and in case where my program returns "5" there is this array: `0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0`  where bits represent numbers from 0 to 10 from left to right and prime numbers marked as "1"-s.
I think, it's impossible for the main "single" thread execute earlier than threads, called by "task" directive because I have `#pragma omp taskwait`. If that is true, then I don't know why I have such strange output. How do you think, what causes the problem here?

Comment: You could try "thread sanitizer" - it may be able to spot the problem.

Comment: You seem to be implementing a sieve. But I don't understand the lowerbound on the `j` loop. Explain? Also, in a sieve each number will be scratched off multiple times, so your `numbers[j]=false` statement should be atomic, except that it would really surprise me if multiple `false` writes would give anything but `false`. Ok, so if you get 5 as output, which primes is it finding?

Comment: You should specify your platform and OpenMP library. I don't see any race condition. But your algorithm is incorrect because the tasks for the inner loop will run in parallel out of order.

Comment: try building with gcc or clang with `-fsanitize=thread` option to check for any race condition.

Comment: I have compiled this code, and got inconsistent values with N=100 for various runs (2 threads). Adding a `critical` pragma for `numbers[j]=false` seems to solve the problem (but of course this cancels all benefits of multithreading). As @VictorEijkhout wrote this is somehow surprising: we do not expect concurrent writes of `false` to the same address give anything but `false` at the end, but still I think that this results in an unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Regarding your edit: I would try putting the `omp taskwait`outside of the `omp single` scope

Comment: Btw, use `atomic` rather than `critical`. Much faster.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I tried on this code, and discovered that `atomic` could not be used on a `std:vector<>` (maybe there are ways, but my knowledge of C++ is quite basic).

Comment: @PierU  I think the problem is that `atomic` wants to do a `+=` type op: read & write both. Try `numbers[i] = numbers[i] && false`? Otherwise for as far as I can tell it ought to work on vectors.

Comment: Generally `atomic write` can be used on `std::vector<>`, but it may not be used on `std::vector<bool>` if it is a space-efficient specialization. In this case use `std::vector<char>`.  Note that 1) there is also a race condition here: `if (numbers[i] == true)` , 2) false sharing may ruin your speed improvement.

Comment: Please check the atomic operations used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69450314/openmp-invalid-controlling-predicate/69452857#69452857) .

Comment: @VictorEijkhout the problem is that `std::vector<bool>` is a space-efficient specialization, so multiple bit manipulations can cause unexpected result.

Comment: @Laci Oh crap. That thing. That's bitten me any number of times.

Comment: @Laci I have tested with `std::vector<char>` instead of `std::vector<bool>` , and it indeed solves the problem (without the need of an `atomic` pragma, even if it would be safer in principle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who commented this question. Laci gave me the answer that I really needed to understand this condition in my code. It is that `std::vector<bool>` is a space-efficient specialization, so multiple bit manipulations can cause unexpected result. Solution is to change `bool` to `char` and you don't need any more directives so this code works like I expected.